# Strange behavior in the creation of new Spring MVC project using STS template project, the URL is not correct and I have to rebuild the project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a doubt about the correct creation of a Spring MVC project.

When I run an imported project (for example the Spring MVC Showcase example downloadable form the STS dashboard), inside the browser URL bar this project have an URL like:

```
http://localhost:8080/project-name/
```

(for example the Web MVC Showcase example have project name: "spring-mvc-showcase" and have the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-showcase/ )
```

Now, my doubt is related to the creation of a new Spring MVC project using Spring Template in STS\Eclipse.

I do the following operation inside STS:

**File --> New --> Project** and appears to me a wizard where I can chose the type of project.

So I chose **Spring Template Project**, now appears to me ano other wizard windows where I can chose the specific typology of Spring Project and I chose **"Spring MVC Project"**

Ok, now appears to me an other wizard windows in which I have to set up:

**Project name** and I insert: **my-spring-project**

**Top level package** and I have insert: **org.mycompany.foo**

Ok, now I run my project on server, this don't run and inside the URL bar of the browser I have not

```
http://localhost:8080/my-spring-project/ (as I would expect)
```

but I have:

```
http://localhost:8080/foo/
```

In the stacktrace I have the following error message:

> WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/foo/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Then if I do a project clean of my project, STS rebuild the project and if I try to run it again the project run well and the URL address still remain:

```
http://localhost:8080/foo/
```

I think that this is a strange behavior and I have not ideas what is the reason about it...

So:

1) Why the URL is not

```
http://localhost:8080/my-spring-project/
```

?

2) Why I have to clean and rebuild my project to run it?

3) I am doing some error in the creation of a standard Spring MVC project?

Comment: what servlet container are you running on?

Comment: @abalogh vmWare vFabric that is a Tomcat with more stuff, why?

Comment: can you post your web.xml, at least the relevant parts?

Comment: @abalogh web.xml posted in a new answer by me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285162/why-template-spring-mvc-project-in-springsource-tool-suite-not-work-with-tom -> might wanna check if this helps

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse > Properties > Web Project Settings : Set as Context Root  `my-spring-project`
Then run the project as you do normal within eclipse. Its should start as `http://localhost:8080/my-spring-project/` . Also do the mapping as showcase project does : `<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home"/>`

Answer (score 0):

This is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You should extend your question if you want to add some more details, and not post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to deploy the new project on your server.

- 1) Open the "Servers" view (Ctrl+3, type "servers")
- 2) right click your Server instance (for example "tomcat 7 at localhost")
- 3)    select "Add and Remove..."
- 4) Select "my-spring-project" from the "available" and "add>" them
- 5) Start the server and access "localhost:8080/my-spring-project/"